# Do separate IntentService instances share the same queue?

Tags: android, android-intentservice

I have a question regarding IntentService

Let's say I have two intent service classes that do separate tasks unrelated to each other.

```
public class TaskA extends IntentService{
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {}        
}
```

And the second

```
public class TaskB extends IntentService{
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {}            
}
```

**If I start TaskA first and then next line start TaskB, would TaskB have to wait for TaskA to finish?**

I am aware that if I start the same intent service again, it is added to a queue but does this apply to an instance or is a global to the whole application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I start TaskA first and then next line start TaskB, would TaskB have to wait for TaskA to finish?

Each `IntentService` has its own worker thread. Specifically, it is an instance of `HandlerThread`, as seen in [the source code to `IntentService`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/IntentService.java). Hence, one `IntentService`'s `onHandleIntent()` should not block another `IntentService`'s `onHandleIntent()`.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html):

> All requests are handled on a single worker thread -- they may take as long as necessary (and will not block the application's main loop), but only one request will be processed at a time.